# UIScrollView steal touches of other views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Hi have the following view hierachy:

[image]

The vertical UIScrollview scrolls if UserInteractioEnabled=NO in the ContainerView but then I can't press the buttons or scroll the horizontal scrollview that is inside. On the other hand if UserInteractionEnabled=YES in the Container View I can press the buttons and scroll the horizontal but not scroll the vertical view. How can I solve this?

Comment: I think it should work. You shouldn't set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, then you will whole interactivity for the view. You can use `scrollEnabled` property of `UIScrollView` if you have to some times. In your case, are you sure that you have appropriately set `contentSize` for your both scrollviews? I am just asking to be sure, because they shouldn't be a problem to each other if one of them is really vertically-scrolled and the other one is horizontally-scrolled.

Comment: I tried to set iserinteraction to yes but then I can scroll the vertical parent scrollview. The contentsize is ok becaude if I change te user interaction to no the vertical one scrolls and to yes the other scrolls and I can also press the button

Answer (score 0):

Try to set canCancelContentTouches property to NO of scroll view.

Comment: What's effect do you want to implement? Enable both scroll view scroll?

Comment: Touch up for the button, horizontal scroll for one of the scrollviews and verticalscroll for the other.

Comment: Do you try when touch the button, call scrollRectToVisible: animated: for both scroll view to make them scroll simultaneously?